# How to add a call in phone number to an existing Microsoft Teams Meeting?

Tags: outlook, microsoft-teams

Since recently, I can add a call-in phone number to Microsoft Teams meetings. For new meetings, this works fine. But I have a meeting with a large number of customers for which I sent the invitation before I had the phone number. So currently, there is no phone number to call in to that meeting. How can I add one, without cancelling the old meeting and creating a new one?

What I tried without success so far:

- Using a number from another meeting (seem to be different "rooms")
- Deleting the link block by hand and trying to add a new one (not possible, the button still says "join the meeting")
- Trying to find out whether the numeric meeting ID can be derived from the one in the link

Answer (score 0):

You can add phone number to the meeting using [Update online meeting API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onlinemeeting-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). You can get the meeting Id by subcribing to notification API please check the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/webhooks?view=graph-rest-1.0) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sadly, it came too late for the meeting, so I cannot tell whether it would have worked. Interestingly, MS support told us (some time after my post here) that this is not possible, so we decided to stop trying and tell our customers that they cannot join by telephone.